# Dependency Injection creating new object everytime an api is called

Tags: node.js, typescript, inversifyjs

Everytime I'm calling an api in inversify-express server the dependency is creating a new object everytime

```
var kernel=new Kernel();
kernel.bind<interfaces.Controller>(TYPE.Controller).to(SyncController).whenTargetNamed(TAGS.SyncController);
kernel.bind<DB_SyncDataDAO>(TYPES.DB_SyncDataDAO).to(DB_SyncDataDAO_Impl);
kernel.bind<SyncService>(TYPES.SyncService).to(SyncService_Impl);
```

Whenever I'm calling an api it is creating new object of each dependency everytime

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Can you you post an answer or flag the one of the answers below as valid?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want some of the dependencies in your object graph to be singletons. You can do that using `inSingletonScope` when declaring a binding:

```
kernel.bind<interfaces.Controller>(TYPE.Controller)
      .to(SyncController)
      .whenTargetNamed(TAGS.SyncController)
      .inSingletonScope();

kernel.bind<DB_SyncDataDAO>(TYPES.DB_SyncDataDAO)
      .to(DB_SyncDataDAO_Impl)
      .inSingletonScope();

kernel.bind<SyncService>(TYPES.SyncService)
      .to(SyncService_Impl)
      .inSingletonScope();
```

As a side note (not related to your question) if `DB_SyncDataDAO_Impl` is an instance (nota class) then you should use

```
kernel.bind<T>("T").toConstantValue(instanceOfT)
```

Instead of:

```
kernel.bind<T>("T").to(classWhichIsAnImplementationOfT)
```

When you use `toConstantValue`, `inSingletonScope` is not required because constant values behave as singletons by default.

Hope it helps :)